# Clipboard is empty after setting text

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following console program:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;    

[STAThread]
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var text = Clipboard.GetText();
    Console.WriteLine("Input Text: " + text);
    Clipboard.SetText(text, TextDataFormat.Html);
    Console.WriteLine("Output Text: " + Clipboard.GetText());
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

The input/output looks like this:

```
Input Text: <table><tr><td>Hello, world!</td></tr></table>
Output Text: 
Exiting...
```

The desired input/output should look like this:

```
Input Text: <table><tr><td>Hello, world!</td></tr></table>
Output Text: <table><tr><td>Hello, world!</td></tr></table>
Exiting...
```

Basically, I want a console program to convert HTML data stored as plain text in the clipboard to actual HTML data and place it back in the clipboard so that I can paste it directly into Outlook email and it will format as a table instead of text. But I don't understand why the `Clipboard.SetText()` call is blanking out the clipboard instead of placing the text in the clipboard with the correct data type. How do I change my program to reach the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. Apparently even when Outlook is in HTML for the message format, you can't just paste HTML into it and have it rendered as a table. Instead, you have to convert the plain text into Rich Text Format, then paste it into Outlook. And apparently converting HTML to RTF in .NET doesn't have a great solution, you have to use a WebBrowser control and a RichTextBox from the Windows Forms library. Here's the code:

```
[STAThread]
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //string input = "<table><tr><td>Hello, world!</td></tr></table>";
    string input = Clipboard.GetText();
    ConvertToRTF(input);
    string text = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Rtf);
    Clipboard.SetText(text,TextDataFormat.Rtf);
}

public static void ConvertToRTF(string html)
{
    RichTextBox rtbTemp = new RichTextBox();
    WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
    wb.Navigate("about:blank");
    wb.Document.Write(html);
    wb.Document.ExecCommand("SelectAll", false, null);
    wb.Document.ExecCommand("Copy", false, null);
    rtbTemp.SelectAll();
    rtbTemp.Paste();
    rtbTemp.Copy();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [other overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/944ft9kf(v=vs.110).aspx) of GetText, as you are specifying the `TextDataFormat`:

```
Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Html))
```

Comment: That got the desired output in the console. But when I then paste the clipboard into a new email in Outlook, it doesn't paste anything, yet I want it to paste an HTML table. Do you know what I would need to change so I could paste it into an Outlook email as a table?

Comment: what if you remove the `TextDataFormat` altogether and use `SetText(text)` and `GetText()`?

Comment: If I don't specify the TextDataFormat, then it just pastes into Outlook as plain text instead of creating formatted table.